# Scala 3 Varargs apply method for case class

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

I am practicing scala 3. I was trying to create a simple Matrix class with a simpler constructor than writing an array of arrays with values. So I wanted to use Seq of Varargs.

```
Matrix(Seq(1,2,3), Seq(1,2,3))
```

Instead of:

```
Matrix(Seq(Seq(1,2,3), Seq(1,2,3)))
```

```
object Matrix {

  def apply[T: ClassTag](arr: Seq[T]*): Option[Matrix[T]] = {
    val width: Int = arr.head.length
    if(arr.forall(_.length == width))
      Some(new Matrix(arr))
    else
      None
  }

}

case class Matrix[T: ClassTag] private(arr: Seq[Seq[T]])
```

This example code compiles in Scala 2, but in Scala 3 I get the following error.

```
method apply in object Matrix is not a legal implementation of `apply` in object Matrix
  its type             [T]
  (arr: Seq[Seq[T]])
    (implicit evidence$2: reflect.ClassTag[T]): 
      Option[com.miloszjakubanis.grid.data.Matrix[T]]
  does not conform to  [T]
  (arr: Seq[Seq[T]])
    (implicit x$0: reflect.ClassTag[T]): 
      Option[com.miloszjakubanis.grid.data.Matrix[T]]
     & com.miloszjakubanis.grid.data.Matrix[T]
```

Compiler will also stop complaining if I remove `case` keyword from my class (but what if I'd like to keep it)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve it, I think this was caused by Scala 3 generating automatic apply functions, unlike Scala 2 (so `new` keywords is not mandatory)

```
object Matrix {

  def apply[T: ClassTag](arr: Seq[T]*): Option[Matrix[T]] = {
    val width: Int = arr.head.length
    if(arr.forall(_.length == width))
      Some(new Matrix(arr*))
    else
      None
  }

}

case class Matrix[T: ClassTag] private(arr: Seq[T]*)
```

Comment: I think you could report this as a bug. Looks like the compiler gets confused because of the varargs<->Seq.

Comment: The `new` keyword was not mandatory in Scala 2 either. Scala 2 also generates an automatic `apply` method. In the earlier version you could write: `val obj: Matrix[Int] = Matrix[Int](Seq(Seq(0)))` and this proves you have two `apply` methods actually: One takes a `Seq[T]*` argument and another takes a `Seq[Seq[T]]`. Making the constructor private in Scala 2 does not work as you expect. So what you did is not overwrite the apply method, but overload it. Try using an `Matrix[Int](Array(Array(0)))` and you'll see they clash each other with the error: `overloaded method apply with alternatives`.